# What method can I use to call a web service from VBA?

Tags: web-services, excel, excel-2002, vba

What is the easiest way to call a web service from Excel (I am using version 2002)?  Please, no third party tools or libraries.  This has to be easy with some VBA that I can paste there, use it, and ever touch.

Comment: Here you go: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140260.aspx

Comment: yea, thanks.  I was planning to answer this one myself after spending 20 minutes before landing on the website you put down :).

Comment: :)  Ain't that always the way it goes?  There ought to be a way to have SO alert you when someone answers your question, because I think I posted this link pretty soon after you posted the question, which might have saved you some time.  :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any especially easy way to talk to SOAP directly from VBA, but a web service with a RESTful interface (i.e. the whole thing can be done via a URL) is easier: I was looking at [this article](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/wlg/5619) just today. Another article I just found is [here](http://www.automateexcel.com/2005/03/17/excel_rest_and_winhttp_thoughts/).

If you're stuck with SOAP, however, you could start by reading [this](http://www.webcontinuum.net/ws_4.aspx) and [this](http://www.automateexcel.com/2004/11/14/excel_vba_consume_web_services/). Frankly, it all looks a bit nasty.